# Object not a collection - Browser in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have written a VBScript and it runs well in HP UFT tool ., where as while the code is made to run in a .vbs file it throws the error Object not a collection :- Browser .

Comment: The `Browser` object is specific to `UFT` and not recognised by pure `vbscript`.  That's why it works in `UFT` and not outside the tool.  You would need to create your own browser object within vbscript and rewrite your code if you need it to run outside of `UFT`.

Answer (score 0):

VBScript is a scripting language, designed to be integrated into many different hosts which each expose their own object model. So, one can run VBScript inside an HTML page within Internet Explorer, or one can run VBScript within a classic ASP page with access to the ASP Response and Request objects, or one can run VBScript within Windows Script Host (which is what a file with the ".vbs" extension runs by default), or it can be hosted within other applications like UFT.

In each case, the objects and names that are available to you by default are determined by the host that is loading the script. This means that you can't just start using objects provided by one host and expect them to exist in another host. While you may be able to share some code, and you can load COM Objects with `CreateObject`, the built-in objects will only be there when loaded on the host that provides those specific objects.

"Browser" is one of those objects, and while UFT may provide it (I'm not familiar with UFT myself), it's not provided by other hosts, which is why when you try to run your script within Windows Script Host it doesn't know what object you're talking about.

Comment: set Browser = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
Browser.Visible = True
Browser.Navigate url_site

Dim browser_name
Browser_name = objDriverSheet.Cells(url_input,"B").Value
 
Browser("name:="&browser_name).Page("title:="&browser_name).WebEdit("html id:=weMemberId","html tag:=INPUT").Set objDriverSheet.Cells(url_input,"F").Value
Browser("name:="&browser_name).Page("title:="&browser_name).WebEdit("html id:=pwd").Set objDriverSheet.Cells(url_input,"G").Value
Browser("name:="&browser_name).Page("title:="&browser_name).WebButton("html id:=waLogin").Click

Comment: I have created a Browser object  ., it again throws the same error

Comment: @Vinith: Whatever "Browser" is in UFT, it's not the same thing as a `CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` object. It isn't a collection, which is why you're getting an error that it isn't a collection. Don't expect any objects that one host provides to be the same in another host unless there's clear documentation showing that they are the same.

Comment: Agreed and understood ., help me in resolving this issue as I have tried so many ways to do it !

Comment: @Vinith: The issue is that what you're saying you're trying to do fundamentally doesn't make any sense. You're probably dealing with some XY problem, and we have no idea what you're actually trying to accomplish here. Why are you trying to use the same code both within UFT and within WSH?